# cakephp passing selection to JS Helper

Tags: ajax, cakephp, helper

I want to get the selected schoolFilter form value and place in [SELECTED VALUE HERE].

```
$data = $this->Js->get('#SchoolFilter')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));

$this->Js->get('#SchoolSchoolId')->event(
'change', $this->Js->request(
        array('action' => 'assign_school_ads/', [SELECTED VALUE HERE], array(
            'update' => '#results',
            'data' => $data,
            'async' => true,
            'dataExpression' => true,
            'method' => 'POST'
        )
    )
);

// School Filter
$schoolFilter = $this->Form->create('School', array('id' => 'SchoolFilter');
$schoolFilter .= $this->Form->input('school_id', array('label'=>'Schools', 'empty'=>'- select -');
$schoolFilter .= $this->Form->end();
```

I have seen variations on this question but without any clear answer, except to just forget using JS Helper. Is it possible within the context of JS Helper? And if not, can I get the value using regular JQuery, then inject it into JS Helper.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :-

```
$this->Js->get('#SchoolFilter');
$this->Js->event('change', $this->Js->request(array('controller'=>'put-ur-controller-ame-here','action' => 'assign_school_ads'),array('async' => true,'update' => '#results','method' => 'post','dataExpression'=>true,'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true,'inline' => true)))));
```

the `serialize()` function sends the form data to the php action so we can see which option was selected and decide what to update in the ajax call.

the form data will be found in `$this->data` in the action (just like after a form has been submited).

Don't forget to add `$this->Js->writeBuffer();` in your layout just before the body closing tag. Otherwise all the ajax code will not be added to your page.

Comment: Shweta, I already have the code you suggest in place (see my code) and it works fine to submit the data. I am trying to get the selected value of the select and send it as a param along with the action: array('action' => 'assign_school_ads/', [SELECTED VALUE HERE]

Comment: Maybe I am not getting your point to send selected value as parameter since seleceted value can be accessed in your function as $this->data['your-controller-name']['field-id'] as serializeForm will send data to your function just like after a form has been submitted.

Comment: For example, I am trying to rewrite the AJAX POST action as: assign_school_ads/3, where 3 is the select menu value. This does not work: array('action' => 'assign_school_ads', $this->data['School']['school_id']. It seems that $data is not available to the Helper in this format until after AJAX has happened. I know I can get $data in the controller, but was wondering if there's any way to use the action to accomplish the same thing.